# Email "email" this Google user account that is associated with has been removed

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I can't access to my Play Console Account and got below email. If I new register, Can I recovery all apps to new account?

Thank you for contacting the Google Play Support Console.
Email "email" this Google user account that is associated with has been removed. This operation is not started or was performed in the Google Play team. Accordingly, no longer associated with the deleted e-mail address "email" can not access the Play Console for developers of.

To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

1. New Play Console account registered to. While you are working to delete the old account on the Google Developers Developers must use a temporary name.
2. Please reply to this email to inform your registered email address when creating a new account Play Console.
3. Finally, after migrating users to a new app catalog in Google Play Console account, cancel / refund the original registration. Sorry, but the private alpha and beta testing group can not be transferred between accounts. Once the app is a private app to send in progress test is automatically disabled test. Setting a new test, and then re-create the test group in the new account.

In Google because you can not send the seller seller account, create a new account to use for a new Developer account, you can transfer a paid app from Google.

If you have any further questions, please let me know.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be up to the Google Play support team so you should ask them. But in general, apps can be transferred to a new account, with various security steps happening to guarantee appropriate ownership.

Comment: Of course. My apps has been transferred to new developer account. Thank you!!